# D3: Delayed Display by setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: d3.js, settimeout, setinterval

I've tried this all day long and haven't got it. I would like to display a string of text in some delaying fashion. For example, at first it displays "a" then waits for a second then display "ab", and then waits for a second then display "abc", so far so on ...

I use D3 to display, function slice to generate partial text string from the alphabet. I use either setTimeout or setInterval. None works. I appreciate some help. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            text {
              font: bold 48px monospace;
            }
            .enter {
              fill: green;
            }
            .update {
              fill: #333;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
            var width = 1000,
                height = 200;

            var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

            function update(data) {
                var text = svg.selectAll("text").data(data);
                text.attr("class", "update");
                text.enter().append("text")
                    .attr("class", "enter")
                    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 32; })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em");

                text.text(function(d) { return d; });
                text.exit().remove();
            }

            // Method 1 - NOT WORKING
            update(alphabet.slice(0, 1)); 
            setTimeout(function(){},3000)
            update(alphabet.slice(0, 2)); 
            setTimeout(function(){},3000)
            update(alphabet.slice(0, 3)); 
            // ...

            /*/ Method 2 - NOT WORKING
            var i = 1;
            setInterval(function(i) {
              update(alphabet.slice(0, i));
              i++;
            }, 1500);
            */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `update` calls need to be in your `setTimeout` function, like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    update(alphabet.slice(0, 1));
}, 3000);
```

`setTimeout` is non-blocking; after the timer is up, it executes the function passed in as an argument.

Edit: You also probably want your code to be like this, removing the update function completely (maybe you have a reason for using many separate `<text>` elements?):

```
var label = svg.append("text");

var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    label.text(alphabet.slice(0, i++).join(""));
}, 1500);
```

Comment: With this it displays "a" then "ab", how do I make it "abc' and further.

Comment: Edited with a way to do that.

Comment: Should the argument i be i++ and also a condition to clearInterval? Anyway, thanks so much. I got it. :)